# Limit selection of following text in Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, selection

Is there any way in Visual Studio Code to prevent "over-selection" when using `Shift + Alt + RightArrow` combo?

E.g. if I'm at the end of line 4 below and I hit that key combo, VS Code selects up until the end of `bar` which is never what I want and means I always have to unselect the last word:

[image: selecting in VS Code]

In JetBrain's WebStorm for example, it only selects up to start of `bar` which is much more useful:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it. This is controlled by the `"alt+right"` and `"shift+alt+right"` settings in the `keybindings.json` file.

By default they map to `cursorWordEndRight` and `cursorWordEndRightSelect` respectively. You can map them to `cursorWordStartRight` and `cursorWordStartRightSelect` by adding the following entries in your keybindings.json overrides file:

```
[
  { "key": "alt+right",
    "command": "cursorWordStartRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  { "key": "shift+alt+right",
    "command": "cursorWordStartRightSelect",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
]
```

Tip: you can get to the `keybindings.json` file that by going to edit Keyboard Shortcuts. There's a link to edit the file at the top.